# Excel-JS - Recalculate does not work

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I cannot make Office-JS recalculate a workbook when in Manual mode: this code does not work

```
// calculate
context.workbook.application.calculate("Recalculate");
await context.sync();
```

But this code does

```
// calculate
context.workbook.application.calculate("Full");
await context.sync();
```

looks like a bug to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more further review of the issue I agree that it was a bug.
I have made the appropriate fix to our APIs and it will release in the coming weeks.

- "Recalculate" will recalculate all dirty cells.
- "Full" will mark all
  as dirty and recalculate.
- "FullRebuild" will rebuild the calculation
  chain, mark all as dirty and recalculate.

Comment: Thanks Philip - that's great - much appreciated.